# Mac OS SQL server need to install?

Tags: mysql, macos

I have always used Xamp or Mamp when I needed an apache server for for php development on my computer (small projects).

I have read that every mac has an mysql and apache server already built in. Is that in any way true?

I have downloaded the MAC os version of MySql but before I installed it I wanted to check if I even needed to do that?

I am also using sequel pro to interact with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Type below command into terminal and it will show you where and if mySQL is installed. If it can't find it, should say so, if it is installed it should show you where it is located

type -a mysql

Comment: getting this back: -bash: -a: command not found 

I actually already went ahead and installed mysql server, and in system preferences clicked "start mysql server"

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X/macOS these technologies like Apache and PHP are included by default, you only need to install MySQL or any other databases and then simply “turn everything on.” to see the apache version on your system type: `httpd -v`
and for php version type: 
`php -v`

Also to start and stop the apache server you can type 
for start `apachectl start`
and to stop `apachectl stop` remember that these two last commands requires root permissions 
`sudo su -`

Comment: Do I have to start apache server to use mysql? I have installed mysql but can't seem to connect to it even though I have started it via gui in system preferences.

Comment: also mysqld is shown to be running in activity monitor

Comment: You can use mysql and create a database without starting apache server, but you need to start mysql server.
for example in my case i have installed apache server with php and mysql, all in one package and used this commands: 
`sudo apachectl stop` stoping apache server 
`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
` start mysql server 
`/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p` start my sql and it is ready to create database.

Comment: I have installed XAMPP server with apache, php and mysql, all in one package so you can see the path with xampp file but i start it separately using the commands above.

Comment: I think part of my problem is/was that I had MAMP installed from before. So I think it was conflicting with the regular mysql install. In any case I just ran the mysql server from MAMP and it is working..

Comment: You can check the version of the mysql, once when you start mysql from the terminal every time it shows the server version and then you can check the MAMP server from phpMyAdmin page using localhost